# Mautic - scoring multiple hits tot he same url by the same customer

Tags: mautic

I'm looking to get a plugin together that will have Mautic increment a Customer's score every time they hit any tracked resource, rather than just the first time. Mautic doesn't seem to support this behavior and I've been having trouble tracing through the code and docs to determine where the resource URL is looked up and where it checks to see if the Customer has already been scored for it, so that I can override that behavior via a plugin. I'm using Mautic 2.5.1.

Comment: For the record, there is already this feature request for the functionality you want: https://github.com/mautic/mautic/issues/929

Comment: Yup, and I've posted to that thread. That feature request is a year and a half old now, though, with no apparent action having been taken on it as yet.